# Trouble while writing a file that can be inputed

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
     void commands(){
    string CMDS = "CMDS";
    cin >> CMDS;
    if(CMDS == "CMDS"){
        cout << "CLS- Clear command line" << endl;
        cout << "Logout- Logs you out of the system" << endl;
        cout << "TFile- Creates a text file" << endl;
        commands();
    }
    else if(CMDS == "CLS"){
        system("cls");
        commands();
    }
    else if(CMDS == "Logout"){
        cout << "Logging out" << endl;
        system("cls");
        Sleep(500);
        mainTitle();
        enterClass();
    }
    else if(CMDS == "TFile"){
        system("cls");
        std::string textf;
        cout << "--Enter Your Text--" << endl;
        ofstream file_;
        file_.open("Text.txt");
        std::getline(std::cin, textf);
        file_ << textf << endl;


        file_.close();
    }
    else{
        cout << "Incorrect choice" << endl;
        commands();
    }
}
```

I need help getting it to work, because the std::getline just closes the program right after I try to write a text file. The program is suppose to let you input text that uses spaces and creates a text file.

Comment: You mean it's not waiting for you to enter a line?

Comment: Yes, It will just exit out of the program

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code snippet you show looks fine.

Comment: Please post a whole program with a `main()` function, so we can try it ourselves.

Comment: I can't, It does not let me format it.

Comment: Without code we can't give you more than vague generalizations like this one: This typically happens when a previous use of >> leaves an end of line in the stream for the getline to pick up. For example `cin >> number` stops parsing as soon as it hits the end of a number and leaves whatever remains of the user's input, often the enter that triggered the input, for whatever parsing follows.

Comment: Why do you have recursion?  The function is calling itself.  You may want to use a `while` statement instead.

Comment: you should check for success when opening a file, i.e. is_open before writing to it.